# Sculpting Distortion 2.8

Tags: mesh, sculpting

After a long time I try myself in sculpting again, using 2.8 and having a problem sculpting on cylinders. As you can see in the picture the faces sort of... splitter off, I would say?
If anyone could push me into the direction on what I am doing wrong with the meshes it would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This is probably an issue with the patterning of the vertices in the base mesh. Can you try enabling dynamic topology in sculpting and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Hey,you were right, I could fix it by giving it more geometry through subdivisions beforehand. Thanks a lot! :)